# MVC : Is there any way to create bundles in view?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm developing a simple CMS with Theme Support. I'm trying to find a way to create css and js bundles for each theme.

I don't want to create Bundles in App_Start.

Something like put my code in _ViewStart.html like this :

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

    Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscripts").Include(
                "~/Scripts/myscript1.js",
                "~/Scripts/myscript2.js")); 
    //and so on...
}
```

Is there any way to do this...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eventually I found the answer:

```
System.Web.Optimization.BundleTable.Bundles
.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/myscripts").Include(...));
```

Just for note : If you really don't need to create bundles in controller/view, for performance manners its best place to create bundles is in app_start.

Comment: That works, but it will run on every page request, kinda crappy.  So what I did for my solution is I made a static method on a helper class that accepts bundles and registers them.  Then it sets "BundlesLoaded" to true.  And BundlesLoaded is true the view code doesn't run with an if block on !BundlesLoaded.